# Is it normal to have water left in front loading washing machine after the cycle?

Tags: washing-machine

I just moved into a new apt, hooked up the washer and decided to do a test run. But I did not realize that the door was not shut tight although I did hear the locking click right before the cycle began. By the time I noticed the water streaming out from the front door, there had already been about half tank of water taken in to the tub, not to mention the flooding on the floor. So I stopped the machine and cleaned up, ran a quick "rinse+spin" cycle, the water in the tub was drained out.

Now, here is the problem: When I started a real load today -- with door shut tight this time, before the machine started taking in water from the hoses, I could hear the sound of water slushing inside. My immediate thought was that there must have been water left from the accident two days ago! The water was not high enough to be visible in the tub but God knows how much still remained under.

I ran this cycle with "no spin" in hopes that the remaining water could be drained out as much as possible. Of course, the clothes were soaking wet after the wash, but I still do not know and cannot tell whether there is still excess amount of water left in the machine under the tub.

Winter is approaching soon (hate to mention it!), I am afraid that if the problem persists, the water left in the machine would freeze. Not just that, I am concerned that the humidity may help grow mold inside the machine.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas as to what I could possible do to resolve the issue. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you don't have a clogged lint filter. On the bottom of the front side, is there a small door where the lint clean out is?

Then, check the drain pipe itself to make sure it's not clogged. Is any water leaving the machine?

Otherwise, sounds like you have a broken or clogged drain valve. This isn't a basic diy project and would involve taking the machine apart. I'd suggest you call a home applicance technician.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the way front loaders save energy is not completely emptying. I had a Maytag for many years that would STINK if it was not used for 3 or 4 days. Yes there could be a problem but on my older unit (now dead) this was normal the tub was dry but there was water in the bottom. The only time I remember it not emptying was after a bed spread with little pom-poms on the edge was washed and that plugged the pump so the machine would not complete a cycle. If your machine is completing its wash rince and spin cycle this is probably normal. If it is not there is a small pump with a check valve after the pump the check valve and or pump could be the problem. I would put the wet clothes back in and let it run the spin cycle If at the end the clothes are just damp not wet it is fine.

Comment: I & family have used at least 6 models of Maytag and Whirlpool front loading washers for 15+ years. None of them when functioning normally retained any more water than a top loading machine (i.e. some moderate level by the drain pump or in the drain hose with check valve). Most people complaining of front washing machines smelling in my experience are either not cleaning the door seal periodically or keep the door closed when not in use (unlike top loaders, front loading washers not in use are like refrigerators not is use, a closed door is sealed and will smell, although faster for washers).